# Dataproc failed to read parquet file in google cloud storage

Tags: apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a parquet file in google cloud storage, then try to read it as below:

```
val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("gs://eng_sandbox1/shaw/testparquet/part-r-00000-b4aecbee-724e-40ea-b868-95f7e3f758a7.gz.parquet")
```

However, I encountered the following exception. One thing I noticed is gs path is different in that exception: bucket name "eng_sandbox1" is missed. Thanks!

```
16/03/02 02:32:18 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 30.0 (TID 270, shaw-cluster-1-w-0.c.fabled-triumph-700.internal): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found : gs:/shaw/testparquet/part-r-00000-b4aecbee-724e-40ea-b868-95f7e3f758a7.gz.parquet
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getFileStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1173)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:385)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:157)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1537)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1542)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1542)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2138)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1542)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1519)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:63)
        at <init>(<console>:65)
        at .<init>(<console>:69)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found : gs:/shaw/testparquet/part-r-00000-b4aecbee-724e-40ea-b868-95f7e3f758a7.gz.parquet
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getFileStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1173)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:385)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:157)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: did you check at least what the error says ? It says that the parquet file `gs:/shaw/testparquet/part-r-00000-b4aecbee-724e-40ea-b868-95f7e3f758a7.gz.parquet` cannot be found !

Comment: I did. The path in my code is "gs://eng_sandbox1/shaw/testparquet/part-r-00000-b4aecbee-724e-40ea-b868-95f7e3f758a7.gz.parquet", but exception complaint about "gs:/shaw/testparquet/part-r-00000-b4aecbee-724e-40ea-b868-95f7e3f758a7.gz.parqu‌​et". The bucket name "eng_sandbox1" is omitted by Spark SQL.

Comment: Is there any other code other than the one line calling sqlContext.read.parquet? What happens if you run: `val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("gs://public-datasets/natality/parquet/part-r-00187-f0ac5c3d-9269-4c0d-ab8e-9ced185287d5.gz.parquet")`?

Comment: Thanks Dennis! I am able to read your file, so it seems my file has something wrong.

Comment: I applied the same code to AWS EMR as follows, and there is no issue. It seems gcs connector has bug.    import org.apache.spark.sql._   
   val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
   val df = sqlContext.read.json("s3://shawtest/people.json")
   df.write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("s3://shawtest/testparquet")
   val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://shawtest/testparquet")

Comment: Does it work if you use a GCS bucket also named "gs://shawtest"?